# How process table is updated by the Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Let's say I have a c program name hello.out. It prints a hello world after every 5 seconds forever. When I execute that program. The instance of that program is called process. Now, when I execute it on a terminal - foreground. What happens to the process page table? Who fills up the process table, and adds an entry in it. How it happens? I understand there is struct task to maintains it. Who fills up this task struct, is it loader?

```
strace ./hello.out 
execve("./hello.out", ["./hello.out"], [/* 54 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x9e3e000
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb7713000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=176783, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 176783, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xb76e7000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0\20\250\366K4\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2012656, ...}) = 0
mmap2(0x4bf51000, 1772124, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x4bf51000
mprotect(0x4c0fb000, 4096, PROT_NONE)   = 0
mmap2(0x4c0fc000, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1aa) = 0x4c0fc000
mmap2(0x4c0ff000, 10844, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x4c0ff000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb76e6000
set_thread_area({entry_number:-1 -> 6, base_addr:0xb76e66c0, limit:1048575, seg_32bit:1, contents:0, read_exec_only:0, limit_in_pages:1, seg_not_present:0, useable:1}) = 0
mprotect(0x4c0fc000, 8192, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0x4bf49000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
munmap(0xb76e7000, 176783)              = 0
fstat64(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 7), ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb7712000
write(1, "Hello world\r\n", 13Hello world
)         = 13
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Where is fork here, what is it happening here. I can see these are system calls. I can make out that printf does a write call with stdout ( the last line). But where is the fork call? What is this brk? Why execve first? what is mmap2 doing here? Also, fstat? I am trying to decode this, and I am not able to understand it in details? Please help me.

Comment: Were do you get the name of the program instance from? It should be called by the name of the file. It may have a different name though if you programmatically changed it but it seems it is not the case

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke a program on a terminal, actually you are asking shell to run your program. Once you run your program, for example,

```
 ./hello.out
```

Now shell will read this command and creates a process using the fork() function. Then the fork() invokes the system call sys_clone(Since Version 2.3.3, passes arguments as it behaves like fork() system call). sys_clone() invokes do_fork(). do_fork() creates the process with all resources(most of them copied from the parent) and stores all information of the process in an object of type struct task_struct.

After the fork() returns the shell program now invokes another system call execve() to replace the address space of the newly created process with the program hello.out in the child process context. execve() system call reads the contents of the hello.out with the help ELF code and fills in the memory and invokes the entry point of the program. In this process the name of the program hello.out is also written into the process structure. You can call who loads this program as a loader(a part of kernel). this is done with the help of dynamic linker if there are any shared libraries that the program hello.out uses.

Comment: I have added more details to my question. Your answer is good, but can you please comment more on it. Please see more details in the question I added.

Comment: you are using the strace command to run your program not the shell. strace will fork() the process and in the child process it runs the execve() command to replace the program hello.out in the child process. So fork() has been invoked by the strace which is a parent process, this fork() will not be traced by the strace, strace only traces the system calls invoked by the child process, and child process first runs the execve() to run the program. brk() and fstat() and mmap() are functions, I need not to explain them, you can use man pages to know what they are.